# Case senstive search for alphanumeric values with Regexp_like plsql

Tags: oracle, plsql, regexp-like

i am trying to find a alphanumeric value in a column, which is case sensitive.
I tried this pattern, but it is not working.

```
`REGEXP_LIKE ('1000 - 2000 test', '^[0-9]{4} - [0-9]{4} test', 'c')`
```

Or does case sensitive not work for alphanumeric values?

Comment: What do you mean with "not working"? Does this return false?

Comment: No values were returned at first. But It was my fault since there was a blank space in the statement and i have removed it and corrected it. Now it gives me a value. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the manual http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/conditions018.htm ;)

```
 select * from (
           select '1000 - 2000 test' a from dual
 union all select '1000 - 2123 TEST' a from dual
) where
REGEXP_LIKE(a, '^[0-9]{4} - [0-9]{4} test', 'c');
```

Returning

```
1000 - 2000 test
```

is case sensitive because of `'c'`, thus the above gives 1 row whereas below, using  `'i'` *case insensitive*, gives 2:

```
 select * from (
           select '1000 - 2000 test' a from dual
 union all select '1000 - 2123 TEST' a from dual
) where
REGEXP_LIKE(a, '^[0-9]{4} - [0-9]{4} test', 'i');
```

Returning

```
1000 - 2000 test
1000 - 2123 TEST
```